# Spark read csv with validation

Tags: csv, validation, apache-spark

I am reading from a csv file with spark's read function

```
val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[CustomClass].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
sparkSession.read.option("delimiter",",").schema(schema).csv("test.csv").as[Customclass]
```

The problem is that when a certain line is cut at the end or when some fields are missing at the beginning, spark is setting null values at the end of the row. I do want to do a validation on read, so that spark tells me or throws an exception as soon as a certain line has not the number of expected delimiters.

Is there a way to do that? My current approach is to read every line in a rdd and do this the validation on my own for each line. And after that I convert my rdd into a Dataframe. So my question is: Is there a way to skip this step and to do a validation on read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `mode` `option` to `FAILFAST`:

```
sparkSession.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST")
  .schema(schema).csv("test.csv").as[Customclass]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any chance to get the record or the line which is malformed?

Comment: With exception? Not that I am aware. In `PERMISSIVE` mode you'll get the record in `columnNameOfCorruptRecord`.

Comment: yes but this option is not available for csv. It only seems to be available for json

Comment: [Not only](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: after 2 years looks also not possible to get column name ((